# Python pandas dataframe : selecting set of elements in array column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has some column like below which contains arrays of different sizes:

```
array_column
["a","b","c","d"]
["d","e","f"]
["h","i","j","k","l"]
["m","n","o","p"]
["q","r","s"]
```

I want to select set of array elements from each cell starting from index =1 till index = (whatever is the array length of that cell -1) and then convert the array into string in which array elements are joined using '/'

So expected output column after selecting required elements will look like :

```
array_column         
    ["b","c"]      
    ["e"]
    ["i","j","k"]
    ["n","o"]
    ["r"]

final_ouput_column         
    "b/c"     
    "e"
    "i/j/k"
    "n/o"
    "r"
```

If it's a simple array for eg which is not a dataframe i would do something like below:

```
array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
new_array = array[1:len(array)-1] // I dont know what should be done //for len(array)-1 for dataframe
print(new_array) . [output is "b","c","d","e"]
print('/'.join(new_array)) "b/c/d/e"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df

               col
0     [a, b, c, d]
1        [d, e, f]
2  [h, i, j, k, l]
3     [m, n, o, p]
4        [q, r, s]
```

---

Use the `str` accessor methods:

```
df.col.str[1:-1].str.join(sep='/')

0      b/c
1        e
2    i/j/k
3      n/o
4        r
Name: col, dtype: object
```